# Damn Small Linux hangs on "Checking for for USB"

Tags: usb, damn-small-linux

On boot of Damn Small Linux on a very old laptop ('98), it goes through the normal routine, until DSL checks for USB devices, at which point it hangs with the message "Checking for for USB...", and the flashing cursor stops flashing. Has anyone seen this before?

I have tried `dsl nousb` and then it works fine, but I can't use my flash drive to get files off of the computer at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Damn Small hasn't been updated in nearly 2 years.
The party's over at [Tiny Core](http://www.tinycorelinux.com/) now :-).